# Jquery autocomplete not able to pass value to hidden field

Tags: jquery, jsp, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been trying to do auto complete using JQuery and JSP, but so far I couldn't get the value in hidden field successfully, I am able to get the department name though.

Could someone point out what exactly is the problem?

Code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#dept").autocomplete( 
"myData.jsp", 
{ 
minChars:4, 
delay:30, 
autoFill:false, 
matchSubset:false, 
matchContains:1, 
selectOnly:1, 
select: function(event, ui) { 
$("#hid").val(result) 
} 
} 
); 

});
```

and in myData.jsp I have // will move the code to Servlet

```
Department t = new Department ();    
    String query = request.getParameter("q");    
    List<String> tenders = t.getDepartments(query); 

    Iterator<String> iterator = tenders.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String deptName= (String)iterator.next();
        String depto = (String)iterator.next();
        out.println(deptName);
    }
```

Comment: which auto complete are using can you give me a link??

Comment: @M.I.T. I am using `jquery-1.2.6.min.js` and
 `jquery.autocomplete.js`

Comment: use like `$("#hid").val(ui.item.id);` or `$("#hid").val(ui.item.value);` whatever u are using

Comment: @M.I.T. You could download scripts I have used from [here](https://anonfiles.com/file/7bc213b4727bc929c46618a8a8845c4b)

Comment: Your version of jQuery is pretty old - you might benefit from upgrading to a later version, particularly if the plugin is keeping up to date with the later versions itself.

Comment: @M.I.T. I have tried both `$("#hid").val(ui.item.id);` and `$("#hid").val(ui.item.value);`, but no luck.

Comment: @richsage I tried with `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` and `jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.2.2`, but still cannot get value in hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#dept").on('blur keyup change', function(){
   $("#hid").val($(this).val()); 
});
```

Try to get the events `blur keyup` and `change` on the `#dept` text input when it gets these events `#hid` will get the value of it.

Comment: `$("#dept").on('blur keyup change', function(){
   $("#hid").val($(this).val()); 
});` will be a separate function? Or I should replace this line? `$(document).ready(function() { `